# MPMoviePlayerController tutorial needed

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

Can anyone please recommend a tutorial for MPMoviePlayerController. I need to play a video with the help of UIButton.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not a tutorial, it shows some code to play video using MPMoviePlayerController:

[Play Video with MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 3.0 and 3.2/4.0](http://iPhoneIncubator.com/blog/audio-video/play-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-ios-3-0-and-3-24-0)

Comment: Thank you Calvin . . . also i need to know what r all the frameworks to be added and headers to be imported???

Comment: Here is a link in developer.apple.com for the MoviePlayer sample code.  Download and open in Xcode to see frameworks and headers....http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html