# How to play a video in iPhone simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, mpmovieplayer

I want to play a video in the iPhone simulator. I have tried with MPMoviePlayerViewController, but its not playing. Anybody has an idea on how to do it ? If there is any good tutorial , please help me find one. Thanx.

NOTE: Question related to MPMoviePlayerViewController not MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941803/mpmovieplayercontroller-tutorial-needed).

Comment: Please mention reason for down voting so that I can improve later.

Comment: The reason for the downvotes is that your question is not specific , also if you would have searched for it on stackoverflow itself you would have found the solution. Check this out before asking any question http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @TejeshwarGill I did searching, found different suggestion, Mostly all are related to MPMoviePlayerController not for MPMoviePlayerViewController. Thats what I raised this question.

Comment: You should try the various chat rooms in that case ... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drag and drop the video file in Your Xcode project

Give the url of video in "videourl"

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videourl];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];     
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer1];
```

It will run perfectly in simulator

This [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Application) Can also help You

Comment: Ya it worked, Even though, without adding the file into project we can't do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ARC.

You can for example call that in your viewDidLoad method and add that controller to your view using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];

   [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    [self addChildViewController:theMovie];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in my header file I write:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

with this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

and in the method in which I init the moviePlayer:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
self.moviePlayer = player;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
initWithContentURL:yourVideoURL];

moviePlayer1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 110);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer1.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                        selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                          object:moviePlayer1];
[moviePlayer1 play];
```